# Function within a function

Tags: matlab, function

Code :

```
function father(earnings)
leftover = earnings - son() - daughter();
disp(leftover)

    function fees = son()
    fees = .50*earnings;
    earnings = earnings - fees;
    end

    function pocketmoney = daughter()
    pocketmoney = .75*earnings;
    end

end
```

Question :

When I give an input argument to the father function of 200, MATLAB displays -75 as an answer. That answer is possible when earnings = 100.
Earning value is changed inside the function son() which is the child function of function father(). All the variables of parent function are available to child function but not the other way round. So how is it that earnings is updated from 200 to 100.

Comment: Just use the debugger! Simply click on the tiny line next to the line number so that a red dot appears, after that call your function `father(200)`. You can then step through everything MATLAB computes!

Comment: Just saying @Manahil: you asked a couple of questions here and yet there are many of them that you have not accepted/gave feedback to. Is there a particular reason for that? Would you please check the answers to your question and accept those that helped you? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting the fees from earnings twice, the earnings variable is shared between the parent function and the child. The son function subtracts the 50% in the function and then the parent function subtracts is again.

The function for son should only return the multiplied value

```
function fees = son()
  fees = .50*earnings
end
```

Comment: But what if I have to keep this code written as it is. No changes are allowed. How would I justify the answer -75 in that case ?

Comment: Why can't you edit the function? I'm not quite following what you are asking.  If you can explain in a little more detail specifically the issue you are having, the perhaps the question can be rewritten to be more useful to other searchers.